# Tabulator update one cell using data from another in the row

Tags: tabulator

I'm using Tabulator (great tool) and I need to update the content of a cell depending of the value of another cell on the same row, which has been edited. How can I achieve that? I tried mutators and accessors but it seems that's not the way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `cellEdited` callback on the editable cell to update the result column.  Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/nzxbcf7g/